# How can I convert a mixed Objective-C and Swift project using ReactJS Native to replace all (boilerplate) Objective-C with Swift code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, reactjs-native

I have a ReactJS Native project and am developing only for iOS now. The initial, basic project has Objective-C classes for development, and I would like to use Swift (partly because Swift and Objective-C interoperate to some degree but I cannot work on a Swift global variable from Objective-C).

The AppDelegate.m provided by ReactJS native may be the only interesting thing in terms of finding an equivalent in Swift; I have not succeed in, for instance, searching for "ReactJS Native 'AppDelegate.swift'" and finding anything that looks like a port of ReactJS Native's default AppDelegate.m.

My AppDelegate.m file, which I do not recall changing, has:

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the BSD-style license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree. An additional grant
 * of patent rights can be found in the PATENTS file in the same directory.
 */

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "RCTRootView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  /**
   * Loading JavaScript code - uncomment the one you want.
   *
   * OPTION 1
   * Load from development server. Start the server from the repository root:
   *
   * $ npm start
   *
   * To run on device, change `localhost` to the IP address of your computer
   * (you can get this by typing `ifconfig` into the terminal and selecting the
   * `inet` value under `en0:`) and make sure your computer and iOS device are
   * on the same Wi-Fi network.
   */

  jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.0.20.3:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];

  /**
   * OPTION 2
   * Load from pre-bundled file on disk. To re-generate the static bundle
   * from the root of your project directory, run
   *
   * $ react-native bundle --minify
   *
   * see http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/runningondevice.html
   */

//   jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"AncientClockPrototype"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Is there an available port that would do the same from Swift?

--UPDATE--

I was looking at a reference project purely in Swift. It is stublike and gives the impression that a calque of the Objective-C above loses as a solution:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  MyPhotos
//
//  Created by Marco Napoli on 10/9/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Organization. All rights reserved.
//
```

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Comment: What have you tried?  The line by line read of that is pretty straightforward ObjC.  It shouldn't be hard to convert to Swift, but SO isn't generally a "write my code for me" site (and without being in context, it'd be hard to know of the conversion is correct).

Comment: I've looked at a working comparison in Swift which does not look like a port of the above at all, with generic, stublike methods. What I've seen looks like there's more going on than a line-by-line calque-y port of the above Objective-C would work.

Comment: The Swift you posted is just the generic template spew from Xcode for an app delegate.  The ObjC is just an implementation of `application:didFinishLaunching:`.  So, you could do a line by line conversion into the implementation of the corresponding method in Swift and ignore the rest of the method stubs.